# How to grep in a log file that has non-ASCII characters?

Tags: grep

I received a log file from a customer that has Chinese characters in it (The month in the log file was in Chinese since this ran on Chinese Windows). I wanted to grep through the files after copying them to my Mac OS X. However, nothing I tried returned a match.

This is how `less` shows the file:

```
22 <CE><E5><D4><C2> 2015 06:08:11,875 Log line 1
22 <CE><E5><D4><C2> 2015 06:08:11,877 Log line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `iconv` utility to convert/remove the special characters:

```
iconv -f ASCII --byte-subst='' logfile.log | grep "searchstring"
```

Note that it will completely remove the special characters, but in my case, this is ok.